# Why do y-axis series labels change when I specify x-axis options?

Tags: primefaces, jqplot

I have a horizontal bar chart generated by PrimeFaces which I have extended to have further control over the configuration:

```
<h:inputHidden value="#{chartBean.chartHeight}" id="chartheight" />

<p:barChart id="chart" value="#{chartBean.chartModel}" orientation="horizontal"
    rendered="#{!empty chartBean.chartModel.series}" 
    title="Grades For Department" min="0" max="5" extender="my_ext" />  

<script type="text/javascript">
    function my_ext() {
        var val=$("#chartheight").val();
        $("#chart").height(val);
        this.cfg.seriesDefaults = {
            renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
            pointLabels: {show: true},
            rendererOptions: {
                barWidth: 20,
                barPadding: 10,
                barDirection: 'horizontal'
            }
        },
        this.cfg.axes = {
            xaxis: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.LinearAxisRenderer,
                tickInterval: 1
            }
        };
    }
</script>
```

Without the 'this.cfg.axes' portion of the script, my y-axis series labels show the names of people (as expected). However, once I add this portion the series labels change to an incremented number instead. Why would that be, and what do I need to do to specify an x-axis configuration while keeping the original labels?

Btw, when hovering over any of the bars, this number is shown instead of the name - whichever version of the script I use.

Many thanks,
Neil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much more investigation, I have found the solution, although I'm not sure if it's an issue with PrimeFaces or jqplot: the xaxis ticks need re-setting again after customising the configuration ....

```
this.cfg.axes.yaxis.ticks = this.cfg.categories;
```

Comment: If you this.cfg.axes.xaxis = {} it will leave the yaxis alone.